# Troubleshooting Compilation Error with lwt_ppx in OCaml: Unable to Compile File

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune, ocaml-lwt

I'm encountering an issue while using `lwt_ppx` and the `let%lwt` syntax as described in the CS3110 textbook's section on promises (https://cs3110.github.io/textbook/chapters/ds/promises.html).

In the code snippet provided:

```ml
open Lwt_io

let p =
  let%lwt s1 = read_line stdin in
  let%lwt s2 = read_line stdin in
  Lwt_io.printf "%s\n" (s1^s2)

let _ = Lwt_main.run p
```

I'm trying to compile the code using dune. My dune file looks like this:

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (libraries lwt.unix lwt_ppx))
```

However, when I run the command `dune exec ./main.exe`, I'm getting the error message "Uninterpreted extension 'lwt'."

I've verified that I have the `lwt_ppx` package installed using `opam list`, and interestingly, the code works as expected in `utop` when I run:

```ml
#require "lwt_ppx";;
#require "lwt.unix";;
#use "main.ml";;
```

What might I be doing wrong with my dune configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lwt_ppx` is a preprocessor, and so also needs to be added to the `preprocess` stanza:

```lisp
(executable
 (name main)
 (libraries lwt.unix lwt_ppx)
 (preprocess (pps lwt_ppx)))
```

But also note that since 4.08 you can use let operators for much the same purpose, without any preprocessir. For example, you can bind `Lwt.bind` to `let*`, then your example can be written as:

```ml
open Lwt_io

let (let*) = Lwt.bind

let p =
  let* s1 = read_line stdin in
  let* s2 = read_line stdin in
  printf "%s\n" (s1^s2)

let _ = Lwt_main.run p
```